# Vue <router-link> not appending params in URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my router link I need to set `id` param that it appends in Vue inspect but not appending it in the URL.

```html
<router-link
            :to="{ name: 'app-gateway-airport', params: { id: slotProps.row.id } }"
            class="mr-2 rounded border boder-button-border w-8 h-8 flex flex-row items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
  <delete-icon />
</router-link>
```

**slotProps.row.id** this variable is set properly.

[image: Click here to view image]

It is not appending the id param in URL.

Comment: What is your route configuration ?

Comment: Its nuxt js.
prasedTo() {
      if (this.skipParsing) {
        return this.to;
      }
      if (_.isString(this.to)) {
        return this.to;
      }
      return this.localePath(this.to);
    }

Comment: Your route name seems wrong - if you have `_id.vue` component, route name should end with `-id`. Edited my answer too. Try it. If it helps, mark my answer as solution. If not, you need to give me more details....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use parameters, you must configure your [route with dynamic component](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

In Nuxt.js you don't define route configuration by hand, Nuxt generates it from folder/file structure instead. In order to view be dynamic (have some parameter), you need to follow [naming convention of Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes) - in this case, your (target) view component should be named `_id.vue`

Also when creating link, be sure to set correct route name: `<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'app-gateway-airport-id', params: { id: slotProps.row.id }}">` (You should be using `<nuxt-link>` instead of `<router-link>` in Nuxt)

Comment: I have created the _id.vue file already. But my question is that In route link <router-link> I am not able to append param for URL.
**Current URL: http://example.com/app/airport**
**Expected URL:  http://example.com/app/airport/1**
I have added **params: { id: slotProps.row.id }** in router link.

Comment: How do a suppose to know it ? You should add all this information into your question in the first place....

Comment: Sorry mate but there is nothing in your question about what link you expect and what link is generated instead. Also nothing about your directory structure, which is essential because Nuxt uses it to generate router configuration....

Comment: Its resolved by changing route name from view to id. Thanks for your support.